# How to adjust QLabel in a PyQt4 program?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlabel

Hello Beautiful People!

I am trying to wrap my head around PyQt4 (never did GUI programming before) so I took [this example code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) and now I am trying to make a QLabel which I can dynamically adjust. I know I need to create a label using QtGui.QLabel and that I need to adjust it using the setText() method.

So I made a new class called myLabelClass() which more or less resembles another class in the code which dynamically adjusts a matplotlib image. The code below however, gives me an AttributeError: 'myLabelClass' object has no attribute 'main_widget'. I think I need to create QLabel object in the initial Canvas class though, and for this I need the main_widget.

So right now I am totally lost. I messed around for hours and tried all sorts of things but I can't get it to work. I more or less understand why it doesn't work, but I have no clue how I could actually make it work. Does anybody know or have some kind of pointer to what I can do to create the label and update it with my countUp() method?

All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
Thanks to the tip of Luke Woodward I changed

```
QtGui.QLabel(self.text, self.main_widget)
```

to

```
QtGui.QLabel(self.text, self)
```

So at least it runs now (WOOHOOO!). I moved the big amount of old code I posted to [pastebin here](http://pastebin.com/MHJ1zdFE). I've got my current [full working code here](http://pastebin.com/kmnTXEWC). I now understand a bit more as well where the chart canvas comes from: matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg which is subclassed in the MyMplCanvas() class.

So I need to find something else to subclass other than that FigureCanvas and I need to get rid of all that matplotlib figure stuff. The thing I wonder about is which class do I need to subclass..? I now have the following code:

```
class MyTextCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)
        self.compute_initial_figure()
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        ########### I added these things below
        self.text = 'this is the initial text' 
        self.create_initial_text()
        ###########

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

    def create_initial_text(self):
        pass

class myLabelClass(MyTextCanvas):
    """This is my own creaed class which more or less resembles the code above."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        MyTextCanvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)        
        QtCore.QObject.connect(timer, QtCore.SIGNAL('timeout()'), self.countUp)
        timer.start(1000)

    def create_initial_text(self):
        QtGui.QLabel(self.text, self)

    def countUp(self):
        for i in xrange(100):
            self.myShinyLabel.setText(str(i))
```

Comment: I think you should try explaining exactly what you're trying to achieve with the label, and then show a cut-down code example that demonstrates just that part of the problem.  If you're like me, you may well find the problem just by going through that process!  You're getting AttributeError simply because your myLabelClass instance has no such attribute (instead of self.main_widget, you need to pass a QWidget instance or None) -- but I think you probably need to think more clearly about how what you want maps onto toolkit concepts rather than concentrating on that.

Comment: "I think I need to create QLabel object in the initial Canvas class though, and for this I need the main_widget."  Sorry, I really don't understand this.  Can you not just set the parent object of the label you create in `create_initial_text` to `self` instead of `self.main_widget`?